# Which Dead by Daylight perks can be considered better at tier 1?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

In Dead by Daylight, perks can only be leveled up through their three tiers, and once you've unlocked a higher tier version of a perk on a certain character, you can't go back to a lower tier version unless you do a prestige reset, which in itself can only be done up to three times per character. Generally, this isn't a problem since perks get more useful as their level increases.

However, as YouTuber Otzdarva pointed out in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ReYFH5x0NU), this isn't always the case. He points out two specific killer perks that are actually better at level 1, in some or all situations:

**Discordance**
This perk notifies you when two or more survivors are working together on a generator, and highlights that generator for you. If you increase the perk's level, the duration of that highlighting also increases. Otz considers this a bad thing, because the highlight always remains for the entire duration, even if the survivors leave the generator before the time runs out. Therefore, at a higher level, it will take longer before this information gets "updated" for you.

**Make Your Choice** (only for certain killers)
When a survivor is rescued from a hook and you are far enough away, this perk makes the rescuer exposed, allowing you to down them in one hit. A higher level increases the duration for which this effect stays active, however this also acts as a cooldown before it can be activated again. This can be a problem for certain fast killers who don't need that much time to catch the rescuer, and could instead benefit from being able to reactivate this perk quicker.

Both of these are conclusions that I'm not sure I would have been able to make on my own. As I'm soon about to prestige my first character for the third time (meaning I'm going to lose the ability of resetting that characters perks), my question is: Are there any other perks that could be considered better if they were left on level 1, especially on the survivor's side, since those weren't mentioned in the video at all?

Comment: There are some perks in this game that are better at Tier 1 but also become worse in another aspect. If an answer explained the pros and cons of these perks it wouldn’t be opinion based.

Comment: Your logic for discordance is flawed. Survivors can move away from the gen regardless of what level your perk is. Its up to the killer to determine if its worth going to the gen or not. The extended highlight just makes it easier to find the gen if you **do** decide to go to it

Comment: @musefan I'm aware that that's probably the intention behind the increasing durations, having more time to process the information. However, what otzdarva means is that when the duration is shorter, you get to know sooner whether the survivors have left or not, which can be a significant upside depending on your playstyle.

Answer (score 1):

**Small  Game** is better in Tier 1 for locating traps and totems since the covered area is smaller.

Comment: I disagree. Its worse because you have to get much closer to the totem before you know its near by. So close that you probably already breaking it when you get alerted